# Написание приложения для облачной Bitrix24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Новичок в Bitrix24. Хотелось бы написать приложение, которое использует базу данных из локальной сети и выводит данные в табличной форме на портале. Я должен просто прописать коннект к своей локальной бд к пхп файле и загрузить его на облачный  портал? Приложение разве увидит мое локальное бд? И как вообще это реализовать?

Comment: Конечно же нет, если только ваша локальная БД будет не доступна для подключения извне.